# Android app showing "Designed for Phones" on Playstore

Tags: android

The Android application I am working on works equally well on phones and tablets. Yet, Playstore displays "Designed for Phones" below the title of the application.

In my application manifest, I have specified small, normal, large and xlarge for supports-screen. I have also set anyDensitry to true.

I am wondering how Playstore decides that "Designed for Phones" must be displayed. More importantly, is there anything I can change in the manifest file to make Playstore understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Google Play will show "Designed for Phones" until you make some tablet-specific configuration in your App, and provide some tablet size screenshots.

You can look which steps you should follow in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)

Inside your App, look for a section called "Optimization Tips", and follow the steps of "Design your App for tablets" in the To DO list.

More info: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/11/google-play-rolls-out-designed-for-phones-tag-of-shame-on-tablets/

Answer (score 0):

Check the Optimisation Tips section in the Android Developer console for your app, it should give some suggestions for removing that tag.